Today, I am talking about dogs
Context: In a talk show, I would like to start the speech like this:
(1) Today, I am going to talk about dogs.
(2) Today, I am going to be talking about dogs.
(3) Today, I will talk about dogs.
(4) Today, I will be talking about dogs.
(5) Today, I am talking about dogs.
I know that the sentences (1)(2)(3)(4) are good to use in this context.
But I don't know if (5) with present continuous referring to future can be used here.

Any of your five would be fine.

You missed out Today, I talk about dogs, which is also perfectly valid for your context. Also note that all your existing 5 phrasings have corresponding abbreviated versions (I'm..., I'll). But I suggest the most common variant is 1a) Today, I'm going to talk about dogs, so I suggest you just use that and forget about "variety for the sake of it".

It's a subtle detail that shouldn't really concern learners (those who need to ask about such things, as opposed to advanced non-Anglophones who are simply gaining more familiarity with English through use). But I think there's a specific potential context where a careful native speaker might prefer Today, I talk about dogs, even though usually that would be a slightly "marked" ("odd") usage. If the speaker has or will be delivering a series of talks on cats, dogs, pet rabbits, etc., Simple Present can be used to heighten the contrast between today's topic and those others.

You might want to avoid, "Today, I embark on a talk about dogs."

Does the sentence "(5) Today, I am talking about dogs." is natural to use here. One of my American friend says that (5) is not commonly used. Is it right?

@PaulTanenbaum some people tell me that I can't use (5) to introduce a topic of a talk show. Is it right?

Today I am talking... relates to @FumbleFingers' comments above. It's valid, but it suggests a different meaning, namely one in a series of talks. "Last week I talked about cats; today I am talking about dogs; next week I will be talking about other household pets."

@PeterKirkpatrick when we don't mention about last week topic and next wek topic, we can't use "today I am talking about dogs". Right?

Here's the proof that Today I am talking about [some subject matter] is perfectly common. Obviously it can be used, because it is used. You haven't given any explanation as to why you think it might not be acceptable / correct, so I don't really see a question here. The only thing worth mentioning is the missing Simple Present as pointed out on the day of the post. What else do you want? Why?

As I said back in May, any of them, including 5, would be fine. I can imagine a talk show host using any of those constructions.

"I don't know if (5) with present continuous referring to future can be used here". But it isn't future. You are already doing it! The simple present would be the most unlikely though it could be used also.

@Lambie You are already doing it!=> I think when I start introducing a new topic, I am not doing it. I only start doing it when I finish introducing the topic of the talk.

To understand what @Lambie means, suppose that I come downstairs one morning and the first thing I say to my wife is “Today I am painting the kitchen.” Then that utterance would be interpreted as discussing the (near) future. But if I the same sentence is uttered instead while I am carrying a ladder and a drop cloth up from the cellar, then it’s reasonable to consider the chore of painting to have already begun, even though the can of paint has yet to be opened. So in this case, the utterance s discussing the present.

I. Going to Future:.
The present continuous tense and "be going to" are both used to talk about the future, but there is some difference in meaning:
The present continuous emphasizes arrangements with another person (definite plans with time/place).
Example:
"I'm meeting Jane at 8 o'clock on Saturday.".
"Be going to" highlights individual intentions or decisions already made.
Example:
"I'm going to wear my black dress tonight."

Present Continuous.

II. For a Talk Show:
All the sentences you suggested are grammatically correct. However, for a talk show simplicity and direct talk are needed to engage the audience.
Before the discussion begins: Use "I am going to talk" or "I will talk" to indicate an upcoming topic. These forms clearly signal future intent or plan, making them more suitable for introductions.
When to use Present Continuous (without going to):
Using "I am talking" can sound odd at the start, as it typically indicates an action already in progress. It works better when referring to something you are actively doing.
Example:.
During the discussion (e.g., after an ad break):
III. Why Present Continuous May Be Confusing
Dynamic verbs like talking, dancing, eating, reading, and playing can refer to either the present or future, depending on the context. Without a clear time marker, the meaning can be ambiguous:

"I'm eating dinner" (present: now).
"I'm eating dinner with friends tomorrow" (future: planned)

For future arrangements, adding a time marker (e.g., "tomorrow") clarifies the meaning. Without it, the verb might be interpreted as referring to the present moment.

A sentence doesn't occur in isolation, but rather in context of the surrounding sentences. That's important to keep in mind. So let's imagine this context:
You walk out onto the stage of a talk show to give a speech. This will be the first thing you say. The audience is not familiar with the topic. You are starting from nothing.
In that situation you are right to think "I know that the sentences (1)(2)(3)(4) are good to use in this context. I don't know if (5) can be used here."
That is because (5) in the present tense sounds abrupt and sudden. By immediately using the present tense, you skipped the introduction. Everything has already begun, in the moment, in the present.
(1)(2)(3)(4) are referring to the future. Those feel more natural. At the start of a speech, tell the audience what they should expect to happen during the rest of the talk (in the future).
Thus, while not absolutely an error, (5) is just not a very good choice.

In what circumstances would the present tense "I am talking about dogs" be acceptable?
As mentioned in the comments, if there are a series of talks about cats, pet rabbits, and so on, or any series of related discussions, one after the next. The speaker is picking things up where they left off yesterday.  Then it could be natural to begin in the present tense.

Everything has already begun, in the moment, in the present.=> I think that if I use the present continuous here, it also refer to the future, which is going to happen during the talk show, not something in the present as you said, since I learned that present continuous is also used to talk about near future

In conversation... the present tense can be a simplified way to speak about the past, present, or future.  That is, about any tense.  Sure, it may refer to the near future, among other things. Also the past. As I said, it's not absolutely an error. My opinion is that it's not the best choice though. If there are compelling reasons to convey immediacy, then maybe.

some natives in this threads says that I can use, some say that I can't. Im so confused, and I don't know if I can use (5) or not.

@LE123  You are framing it as a yes/no question "can I use it or not". I believe that is misguided. There are many subtleties in language. (5) is not an extreme grammatical mistake. However based on the context, which is very specific, if you have no history with this audience, then it sounds odd to jump instantly into the present tense, in my opinion. You should introduce the topic. What will you talk about.


(5) Today, I am talking about dogs.

[be+ing] has two usages.

when something is being done or someone is doing something (present continuous)


I am now talking about dogs.


a foreseeable future; an impening future; an immediate future


Today, I am talking about dogs.

The time adverb here is very important in the context of yours because the time adverb here is a key element which defines the direction of the tense.

If so, with the context that this is the first time I have met the audience and there is no previous meetings before today, Can I still use "am talking" here? Other natives say that it will sound odd to introduce a new topic in a talkshow or a seminar with using "am talking". How is your opinion?

You should know that you already have answers or comments from natives here and that the audience in a talk show is/are more likely to be people who come to that show for the first time.

There are some opinions from natives that the “m talking” is only natural in this context : "Yesterday I talked about cats. Today I'm talking about dogs." if there is no previous talk show before today, it is unnatural to use. That is the thing I’m confused

"Any of your five would be fine. – Paul Tanenbaum  Commented May 17 at 15:03"  You could trust his comment which has 6 upvotes as of now.

The last version is technically wrong. But it is widely used in informal speech.
If you are attending a conference on animals, a speaker might take the stage and say, "Yesterday I talked about cats. Today I'm talking about dogs." and everyone would understand what his next presentation will cover. It is colloquial speech, and it occurs quite frequently.
This use of the simple present as both present and future is common in creoles and very informal speech.

"Yesterday I talked about cats. Today I'm talking about dogs."=> what if this is the first time I met the audience, there is no talk before. Today is the first meeting with the audience, I want to introduce the new topic. If "am talking" can be used here?

@LE123 - Marginally, but it's not a good idea. Without context it will sound wrong. It could be used after some introduction. Bear in mind that this is very informal speech being used in a formal setting, so the rules tend to be a bit subtle. As you are  a non-native English speaker I'd advise against pushing the envelope just yer.

It could be used after some introduction=> what is some introduction? Is that like this " good morning everybody, my name is X, Today Im talking about dogs, as you know dogs are a loyal animal ...." So I think good morning and introduce my name is introduction. Right?

@LE123 - Sounds good to me. Keep in mind that it establishes you as more of a doer or practical sort than a thinker. At least, that is the sort of impression this technically incorrect construction gives.

The last version is technically wrong.=> Why do you say that "m talking" is wrong? I often see people use be+ving (present continuous) to talk about the near future. For example: I'm talking/ meeting with Jane this evening (this evening is the near future) . I still don't under stand why "Today (is the near future), I'm talking about dogs..." is considered wrong.

Technically, the present tense is used for, well, the present. Not the future, since that is what the future tense is for. In this case, "Today I'm talking about dogs" should be, "Today I will be talking about dogs." Using the present tense to talk about the future is common in informal speech when context is supplied, but it's a lazy way of speaking.
